# Ansible Conditional - Compare registered variable to a value

Tags: ansible, jinja2, chef-infra, comparison-operators

I need your help since I'm at a complete loss here.
We started checking Ansible as a configuration manager (the AWX Project). We are currently based on a Chef Infra configuration manager.
In chef when you want to control a resource from happening you can use `only_if` or `not_if`

```
filesystem "Test mount" do
    fstype "xfs"
    mount "/tmp/test"
    device "/dev/sda"
    action [:create, :enable]
    not_if { File.exists?("/tmp/test") }
end
```

After checking in Ansible I saw that conditionals are the equivalent for Chef guards.

My problem is this:
In my example I'm trying to see if a service exists and if it does, do action A, if not, do action B.
This is my playbook:

```
---
- name: Test of powershell
  hosts: all
  tasks:
  - name: test if ABCD service exists
    win_shell: |
      $a = Get-Service -Name ABCD -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
      if ($a) {
        return $(Write-Host -NoNewline $true)
      }
      return $(Write-Host -NoNewline $false)
    register: ABCDExists
  
  - name: print ABCDExists value
    debug:
      var: ABCDExists
      verbosity: 3
  
  - name: Write service info if service exists
    win_shell: |
      $a = Get-Service -Name ABCD
      New-Item -Path c:\temp\ -Name "text.txt" -ItemType File -Force
      Set-Content -Path C:\temp\test.txt -Value "$($a | select-object -property *)"
    when: ABCDExists is "True"

  - name: Write service doesn't exists
    win_shell: |
      New-Item -Path c:\temp\ -Name "text.txt" -ItemType File -Force
      Set-Content -Path C:\temp\test.txt -Value "Service ABCD doesn't exists"
    when: ABCDExists is "False"
```

As you can see, the latest try for the conditional is `ABCDExists is "True"`\ `ABCDExists is "False"`.

This if after I tried doing:
`ABCDExists == False`
`ABCDExists == "False"`
`ABCDExists|string() == "False"`

I really at a loss here, I cannot understand where to look in Jinja documentation for the comparison operators or such.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE:
After testing `ABCDExists | bool` I managed to skip one of the tasks, but not the one I expected.

These are the logs from the running job (After the change):

```
ansible-playbook 2.9.10
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/var/lib/awx/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible-playbook
  python version = 3.6.8 (default, Apr 16 2020, 01:36:27) [GCC 8.3.1 20191121 (Red Hat 8.3.1-5)]
Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
SSH password: 
host_list declined parsing /tmp/awx_183_ngdrbth5/tmph5taum3q as it did not pass its verify_file() method
Parsed /tmp/awx_183_ngdrbth5/tmph5taum3q inventory source with script plugin

PLAYBOOK: powershell_test.yml **************************************************
1 plays in powershell_test.yml

PLAY [Test of powershell] ******************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
task path: /tmp/awx_183_ngdrbth5/project/powershell_test.yml:2
Using module file /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible/modules/windows/setup.ps1
Pipelining is enabled.
<server01> ESTABLISH WINRM CONNECTION FOR USER: User@Domain.com on PORT 5985 TO server01
EXEC (via pipeline wrapper)
ok: [server01]
META: ran handlers

TASK [test if ABCD service exists] *****************************************
task path: /tmp/awx_183_ngdrbth5/project/powershell_test.yml:5
Using module file /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible/modules/windows/win_shell.ps1
Pipelining is enabled.
<server01> ESTABLISH WINRM CONNECTION FOR USER: User@Domain.com on PORT 5985 TO server01
EXEC (via pipeline wrapper)
changed: [server01] => {
    "changed": true,
    "cmd": "$a = Get-Service -Name ABCD -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue\\nif ($a) {\\n  return $(Write-Host -NoNewline $true)\\n}\\nreturn $(Write-Host -NoNewline $false)",
    "delta": "0:00:00.484379",
    "end": "2020-09-01 01:34:23.412182",
    "rc": 0,
    "start": "2020-09-01 01:34:22.927802",
    "stderr": "",
    "stderr_lines": [],
    "stdout": "True",
    "stdout_lines": [
        "True"
    ]
}

TASK [print ABCDExists value] **********************************************
task path: /tmp/awx_183_ngdrbth5/project/powershell_test.yml:14
ok: [server01] => {
    "ABCDExists": {
        "changed": true,
        "cmd": "$a = Get-Service -Name ABCD -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue\\nif ($a) {\\n  return $(Write-Host -NoNewline $true)\\n}\\nreturn $(Write-Host -NoNewline $false)",
        "delta": "0:00:00.484379",
        "end": "2020-09-01 01:34:23.412182",
        "failed": false,
        "rc": 0,
        "start": "2020-09-01 01:34:22.927802",
        "stderr": "",
        "stderr_lines": [],
        "stdout": "True",
        "stdout_lines": [
            "True"
        ]
    }
}

TASK [Write service info if service exists] ************************************
task path: /tmp/awx_183_ngdrbth5/project/powershell_test.yml:19
skipping: [server01] => {
    "changed": false,
    "skip_reason": "Conditional result was False"
}

TASK [Write service doesn't exists] ********************************************
task path: /tmp/awx_183_ngdrbth5/project/powershell_test.yml:26
Using module file /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible/modules/windows/win_shell.ps1
Pipelining is enabled.
<server01> ESTABLISH WINRM CONNECTION FOR USER: User@Domain.com on PORT 5985 TO server01
EXEC (via pipeline wrapper)
changed: [server01] => {
    "changed": true,
    "cmd": "New-Item -Path c:\\\\temp\\\\ -Name \\"text.txt\\" -ItemType File -Force\\nSet-Content -Path C:\\\\temp\\\\test.txt -Value \\"Service ABCD doesn't exists\\"",
    "delta": "0:00:00.531259",
    "end": "2020-09-01 01:34:26.380055",
    "rc": 0,
    "start": "2020-09-01 01:34:25.848796",
    "stderr": "",
    "stderr_lines": [],
    "stdout": "\\r\\n\\r\\n    Directory: C:\\\\temp\\r\\n\\r\\n\\r\\nMode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                  \\r\\n----                -------------         ------ ----                                                                  \\r\\n-a----         9/1/2020   9:34 AM              0 text.txt                                                              \\r\\n\\r\\n\\r\\n",
    "stdout_lines": [
        "",
        "",
        "    Directory: C:\\\\temp",
        "",
        "",
        "Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                  ",
        "----                -------------         ------ ----                                                                  ",
        "-a----         9/1/2020   9:34 AM              0 text.txt                                                              ",
        "",
        ""
    ]
}
META: ran handlers
META: ran handlers

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
server01    : ok=4    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=1    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `debug` output for variable `ABCDExists` we can see a couple of things which might change depending on the existence of service.

```
       "failed": false,
       "stdout": "True",
```

**We can have the tasks with `when:` condition as below to compare the boolean value of `"failed"`:**

```yaml
  - name: Write service info if service exists
    win_shell: |
      $a = Get-Service -Name ABCD
      New-Item -Path c:\temp\ -Name "text.txt" -ItemType File -Force
      Set-Content -Path C:\temp\test.txt -Value "$($a | select-object -property *)"
    when: not ABCDExists.failed | bool

  - name: Write service does not exists
    win_shell: |
      New-Item -Path c:\temp\ -Name "text.txt" -ItemType File -Force
      Set-Content -Path C:\temp\test.txt -Value "Service ABCD doesn't exists"
    when: ABCDExists.failed | bool
```

**Another way is to compare the text output in `"stdout": "True",`:**

```yaml
  - name: Write service info if service exists
    win_shell: |
      $a = Get-Service -Name ABCD
      New-Item -Path c:\temp\ -Name "text.txt" -ItemType File -Force
      Set-Content -Path C:\temp\test.txt -Value "$($a | select-object -property *)"
    when: ABCDExists.stdout == 'True'

  - name: Write service does not exists
    win_shell: |
      New-Item -Path c:\temp\ -Name "text.txt" -ItemType File -Force
      Set-Content -Path C:\temp\test.txt -Value "Service ABCD doesn't exists"
    when: not ABCDExists.stdout == 'True'
```

There are some ways to [test conditions](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html).

Comment: Hey, it helped me alot, now one of the tasks skips and the other not, but for some reason, not the one I expected.
The task that should run when it's true skips, and the other when it is false it running.
The result from the first check to see if the service exists returns true:
{ .............
    "rc": 0,
    "delta": "0:00:00.484379",
    "end": "2020-09-01 01:34:23.412182",
    "stdout_lines": [
        "True"
    ],
    "stderr_lines": [],
    "_ansible_no_log": false
}

sorry for the formating, I'm new to Stack Overflow so I don't know if to reply in a new comment or not...

Comment: Comments don't play as well with formatting. You could edit your question with an *Update*, and post these details.

Comment: Will `ABCDExists` have boolean value or return code (`"rc": 0`)?

Comment: I've added the logs, it does return "rc": 0 but I think it will always return zero because I return a value nonetheless.

Comment: It seems we can match `stdout`, as it generates `"stdout": "True",`. I will update my answer, see if that works out.

Comment: Just wanted to update that using the `ABCDExists.stdout == 'True'` it worked correctly.
I really wonder about the `ABCDExists | bool` and why it didn't work correctly.. but in any case you helped me greatly, have a nice day!